# Select TOP + GROUP BY + SHORT in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assume the following `stockInWarehouse` schema:

```
{
  product_db: {
    mappings: {
      stockInWarehouse: {
        properties: {
          sku: {
            type: "string"
          },
          arrivalTime: {
            type: "date",
            format: "dateOptionalTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The data in `stockInWarehouse` look like:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "product_db",
        "_type": "stockInWarehouse",
        "_id": "1",
        "_source": {
          "sku": "item 1",
          "arrivalTime": "2015-11-11T19:00:10.231Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product_db",
        "_type": "stockInWarehouse",
        "_id": "2",
        "_source": {
          "sku": "item 2",
          "arrivalTime": "2015-11-12T19:00:10.231Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product_db",
        "_type": "stockInWarehouse",
        "_id": "3",
        "_source": {
          "sku": "item 1",
          "arrivalTime": "2015-11-12T19:35:10.231Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product_db",
        "_type": "stockInWarehouse",
        "_id": "4",
        "_source": {
          "sku": "item 1",
          "arrivalTime": "2015-11-13T19:56:10.231Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product_db",
        "_type": "stockInWarehouse",
        "_id": "5",
        "_source": {
          "sku": "item 3",
          "arrivalTime": "2015-11-15T19:56:10.231Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What i am trying to do is to **fetch TOP documents by arrivalTime** (aka most recent documents) however i want them to be **sorted by another field (sku)** and **limit to available sku**. The expected result would look like this:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "product_db",
        "_type": "stockInWarehouse",
        "_id": "5",
        "_source": {
          "sku": "item 3",
          "arrivalTime": "2015-11-15T19:56:10.231Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product_db",
        "_type": "stockInWarehouse",
        "_id": "4",
        "_source": {
          "sku": "item 1",
          "arrivalTime": "2015-11-13T19:56:10.231Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "product_db",
        "_type": "stockInWarehouse",
        "_id": "2",
        "_source": {
          "sku": "item 2",
          "arrivalTime": "2015-11-12T19:00:10.231Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I sort by `arrivalTime`, the result sku list will contains `item 3, item 1, item 1, item 2, item 1` (duplicate). If I sort by `sku`, result list will not reflect correct arrivalTime order.

Is this type of query possible in Elasticsearch? How can I archive this?

Comment: My guess is that you could get close by using a Bucket Aggregation to group by sku, and a standard Sort to order by arrivalTime. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "terms_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sku",
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "max_date_agg": "desc"
        }

      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date_agg": {
          "max": {
            "field": "arrivalTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have made `size : 100` assuming you have lot of products.

**Note** You need to add `index : not_analyzed` to your `mapping` of sku
This is the result of the query

```
"aggregations": {
      "terms_agg": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "item 3",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "max_date_agg": {
                  "value": 1447617370231,
                  "value_as_string": "2015-11-15T19:56:10.231Z"
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "item 1",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "max_date_agg": {
                  "value": 1447444570231,
                  "value_as_string": "2015-11-13T19:56:10.231Z"
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "item 2",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "max_date_agg": {
                  "value": 1447354810231,
                  "value_as_string": "2015-11-12T19:00:10.231Z"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

I hope it helps!!